# Better performance: fancy objects or lots of functions?

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming

**Examples in Python**

I'm working with data that is only characterized by two values: a start and an end point.  Let's imagine these correspond to chromosome start and end points.  So data would look like:

```
(1,50)
(20, 500)
(40, 80)
...
```

Now I need to add some functionality.  For example, imagine I want to start using these as sets, or sort these by the start value.  My OOP-biased first inclination is to create a small class for these objects that would have attributes like `start, end` and methods like `as_set()`.

```
class Range(object):
    def __init__(start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def as_set(self):
        """ Set of integers on range {start, end} """
        return set(range(self.start, self.end))
```

The alternative design approach is to just create a library of functions with a strict call signature:

```
 def as_set(start, end):
     return set(range(start, end))
```

I figure the `Range` object, having attribute access, will make operations involving sorting much easier, but at what cost. In a semi-performance critical situation, would you avoid using classes at all costs, or is the memory overhead usually worth the gains?  In other words, under what circumstances should one avoid implementing new classes to store simple data?  Would this slow down an NP-hard algorithm for example, or just add memory overhead, while retaining, more or less, the big-O of the alogorithm?  I know that this depends on the usecase, but I'm looking for general considerations regarding when to go one route vs. another.

Comment: dont early optimize .... do whatever makes the most sense and then profile it to locate and improve bottlenecks

Comment: This is hard to answer in the general case; trading speed for space is a classic optimisation in computing. In your specific case, I would write the function, then memoize it (Google "dynamic programming" if you don't know what I mean) if there was a performance issue, ensuring that each unique `(start, end)` pair's `set` would only be created once. Your `Range` is definitely overkill - as a rule, if you only implement `__init__` and one other method, you shouldn't be using a class.

Comment: Thanks jon.  I never heard that rule of thumb.  What about situations where you want attribute access?  Is attribute access not worth the memory overhead, you're saying?

Comment: If you do want `start` and `stop` (and don't forget `step`!) you could create a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of a class; this would be more memory-efficient (*"they are lightweight and require no more memory than regular tuples"*). You could then have a memoized factory function to easily create the appropriate instances. But I agree with @JoranBeasley, don't optimise early.

Comment: as a general rule of thumb classes are data __combined__ with actions ... if its just data a class is probably not the appropriate data structure

Comment: Thanks guys.  Yes, I do need to use namedtuples; I never thought of it that way... data AND actions.

Comment: Making `as_set` a method means you could hide the internals of how you're representing the data for your `Range` objects within the class thus making it easier to change later without have to modify a bunch of external "utility" functions you or someone else wrote. It's called [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and is a key feature of the object-oriented programming paradigm.

Comment: I kept thinking about this on the walk home, and came up with [this](https://gist.github.com/textbook/aa174274a74b62ad3d3d) class implementation, kind of a `set`/`range` cross with caching. I'm sure there's stuff I've missed, but hopefully you'll find it interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Very cool, thanks.  I"ll study it